# Extra indent in Vi/Vim Tcl code block indentation

Tags: indentation

I am using the `gg=G`, `=ap` etc. paradigms to reformat some code. This code is in tcl:

```
proc something { foo bar } {
set foo [yadda yadda]
set foo [yadda yadda]
set foo [yadda yadda]
}
```

When I try adjust indents, the formatting changes to:

```
proc something { foo bar } {
    set foo [yadda yadda]
        set foo [yadda yadda]
        set foo [yadda yadda]
}
```

I would expect all the set statements at the same indent level. Is there a way to do that?

This is the "VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr  4 2017 18:14:54)" what comes with MacS Sierra, invoked as "vi".

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us the output of `:filetype` and `:verbose set sts? ts? sw? cindent? indentexpr? autoindent? smartindent?` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `&filetype` properly detected? Vim 7.4 runtime should already include the [correct indent file](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/indent/tcl.vim).

Execute `:scriptnames` to list all sourced files and look for `/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/tcl.vim`.

If it's missing, make sure you have this line in your vimrc file:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Read [Indenting source code](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code#File-type_based_indentation) on the Vim Tips Wiki for more info on file-type based indentation.

Comment: Thanks for getting me started. tcl.vim is not listed as a plugin in OSX Sierra. My Deniers of IT Services have my mac locked down so I can't add files to that directory, and the other place I need to edit it is on a F5 load balancer. The F5 lists tcl.vim as a plugin, but it's vim 7.0.